# How to get only unique values in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to take only unique values from collection. For example:

```js
const userID = `user1`;
const users = await Chat
  .find({'$or': [{to: userID}, {from: userID}]})
  .select(`-_id to from`)
  .lean();

// users will be like:
[
 {from: `user1`, to: `user2`},
 {from: `user1`, to: `user2`},
 {from: `user1`, to: `user2`},
 {from: `user2`, to: `user1`},
 {from: `user3`, to: `user1`},
 // ... 10089 more items
];

// and I want this in result 
const result = [`user2`, `user3`]; // exclude current user too
```

I know that I can do this using JS. I can create an array from users and run `new Set()`, but it will be slow. Can Mongoose do this instead of me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try aggregation query,

- `$match` your condition
- `$group` by null and construct unique array of `from` user and `to` user
- `$setUnion` to get unique `users` from `from` and `to` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above union array and remove current user

```
const userID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`user1`);
const users = await Chat.aggregate([
  { $match: { $or: [{ to: userID }, { from: userID }] } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      from: { $addToSet: "$from" },
      to: { $addToSet: "$to" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $setUnion: ["$from", "$to"] },
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", userID] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).exec();

console.log(users[0].users);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yz15NDqrNn3)

Comment: It seems strange to me. It's not working. The result is an empty array (console.log(users)). I've deleted the second and the third element from the aggregate pipeline array and the result is an empty array too.

Comment: i am not sure, can you try adding .exec() after function, like i have updated answer.

Comment: I added. `const users = await Chat.aggregate([
      {$match: {$or: [{to: userID}, {from: userID}]}},
    ]).exec();

    console.log(users);`. Your code and this returns only [ ]

Comment: what is actually in `from` and `to` field in database collection?

Comment: Types.ObjectId

`const schema = new Schema<ChatDocument>({
  date: {type: Date, required: true},
  read: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  content: {type: String, required: true},
  to: {type: Types.ObjectId, ref: `User`, required: true},
  from: {type: Types.ObjectId, ref: `User`, required: true},
});`

Comment: I think, I should add `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID)`, right?

Comment: yes your are right it require to convert your input to objectid